# Delphi XE login bug

Tags: delphi

When i login in my app with right username and password initially i get error message for wrong username or password, then the next time i click login button the login works fine.I am a delphi hobbyist so don't judge me hard.

```
type
  TfmLogin = class(TForm)
    pnlMain: TPanel;
    lblUserName: TLabel;
    SQLConnection: TSQLConnection;
    DataSource: TDataSource;
    ClientDataSet: TClientDataSet;
    SQLQuery: TSQLQuery;
    DataSetProvider: TDataSetProvider;
    edtUserName: TEdit;
    lblPassword: TLabel;
    edtPassword: TEdit;
    btnRegistration: TButton;
    btnLogin: TButton;
    SQLTable: TSQLTable;
    procedure btnRegistrationClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnLoginClick(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  fmLogin: TfmLogin;

implementation
```

This is match function

```
function MatchPass(Table : TSQLTable; const UserName, Password : string): Boolean; 
begin
 Result := Table.Locate('Username;Password', VarArrayOf([username,password]),[]);
end;
```

And this is the login button procedure

```
procedure TfmLogin.btnLoginClick(Sender: TObject);
var
UserName : string;
Password : string;
begin
 UserName := edtUserName.Text;
 Password := edtPassword.Text;

     if(MatchPass(SQLTable, UserName, Password)) then    //1.Why first time returns false
     begin
      with TfmMain.Create(nil) do
        try
          ShowModal; //3.And opens my main form
        finally
          free;
        end;
     end
      else
    ShowMessage('Wrong name or pass'); //2.And enters else and the second time returns true
    end;
```

Comment: Pretty unlikely that we can explain this with so little information. Surely the explanation lies in detail that we cannot see.

Comment: We can't debug this for you, because as @DavidHeffernan says, the problem must lie in something we cannot see.  I suggest you temporarily add the UserName and Password values which have been rejected to your ShowMessage call.  Also are you 100% certain that SqlTable is open when you first call it?

Comment: Thank you guys, that is pretty much my login unit except registration button. Registration form work's fine and inserts fields into database properly (autoincrement id field,username and password) . @MartynA SQLTable is checked active from Object inspector, nowhere in login unit is used SQLTable.Open or Close methods.

Comment: Try to refresh the table before locate. Like `Table.Close; Table.Open; Table.Locate(...`

Comment: @ValMarinov Thank you this fix my issue.

Comment: @ValMarinov Тей като гледам ще е на български, благодаря ти оправи се с refresha )

Comment: You are welcome. Бъди здрав и успехи.

Comment: It is improper here to edit your question title to say SOLVED. Please do not do so. I've rolled back your edit.

Comment: Ok  excuse me. I should read the rules.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why not (from head)  :

```
procedure TLogin_Form.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Query1.Active:=false;
Query1.SQL.Clear;
Query1.SQL.Text:= 'select [user],[password] from  users where  [user] ='+QuotedStr(cxlookupcombobox1.text) +' and [password]='+QuotedStr(cxTextEdit1.Text);
Query1.Open;
if Query1.FieldByName('password').AsString<>''
then  begin
ModalResult := mrOK ;
end else
ModalResult := mrNone;
```

You dont need to match anything because password must match anyway.

Comment: Sending username and password without using parameters is dangerous.

Comment: Also, depending on the database engine, this query is case-insensitive.

Comment: well, you can use parameters too  instead of quotedstring like : where user=:p1 and password=:p2. Then just pass the parameters. Password is case sensitive in almost all databases. Well,from my experience....